# Custom routing without overriding core CMS routing

Tags: php, routes, silverstripe

I'd like to implement some custom routing in my site that will end up being a database lookup to define the content returned. I've been looking at [this example](http://www.ssbits.com/tutorials/2011/using-a-nested-controller-for-generic-url-handling/) which isn't working as intended (mainly because it was for SS2).

I have my main routes.yml:

```
---
Name: mysiteroutes
After:
  - 'framework/routes#coreroutes'
---
Director:
  rules:
    'create//$Action': 'CreateController'
    'profile//$Person/$Action/': 'ProfileController'
```

My _config.php:

```
Director::addRules(2, array(
    '$URLSegment//$Action/$Detail/$Option' => 'BaseController',
));
```

My BaseController:

```
class BaseController extends ModelAsController {

    public function getNestedController() {
        if ($this->getRequest()->params('URLSegment') =='Test') {
            return new ProfileController();
        } else {
            return parent::getNestedController($this->getRequest()->params('URLSegment'));
        }
    }
}
```

My ProfileController:

```
class ProfileController extends Controller {

    private static $allowed_actions = array(
        'test'
    );

    public function index(SS_HTTPRequest $request) {
        return $this->renderWith(array("ProfileHomePage", "Page"));
    }

    public function test(SS_HTTPRequest $request) {
        print_r($request->params());
        return $this->renderWith(array("ProfileHomePage", "Page"));
    }
}
```

This works correctly without the dynamic route however I'd like to catch anything under (for example) `/example/` check if there is a db entry for it (via a custom script I'm yet to write), if not route it through the cms (i.e. check if there is a predefined route for it, then if there is a page for it before returning a 404). How can I achieve this?

I did try `'$URLSegment//$Action/$Detail/$Option': 'ProfileController'` which I could route correctly and load custom templates etc however it meant `/admin/`, `/create/` and other predefined routes wouldn't work.

Comment: Maybe you want __magic methods?

Comment: It's more to do with the routing and not overriding the core functionality, not sure how __magic methods would help rectify this?

Comment: You want dynamic routes. You can pass url segment or uri part or full request into __get() method for custom calls for any your (pre/post/partial)-routes. And here you can have separate config.

Comment: As I understand it this would work for calling a function however my config would still override the predefined ones set by SilverStripe, which is more the issue I'm facing.

Comment: _Possibly_ related: https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/issues/6193

Comment: @RobbieAverill nah, that one is still defined rather than using $URLSegment and I have a // in my route already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way of doing it, though there might be a better way:

```
---
Name: mysiteroutes
---
Director:
  rules:
    'create//$Action': 'CreateController'
    'profile//$Person/$Action': 'ProfileController'
---
Name: modelascontrollerroutes
After: '#rootroutes'
---
Director:
  rules:
    '': 'HomePage_Controller'
    '$URLSegment//$ID': 'BaseController'
```

Base Controller:

```
class BaseController extends ModelAsController {

    public function getNestedController() {
        $params = $this->getRequest()->params();
        if (/*check for $params['URLSegment'] here */) {
            //return custom controller
        } else {
            return parent::getNestedController();
        }
    }
}
```

Example custom controller:

```
class PersonController extends Controller {

    private static $allowed_actions = array(
    );

    public function index(SS_HTTPRequest $request) {
        return $this->renderWith(array("PersonHomePage", "Page"));
    }
}
```